# It is possible to send using GenericEntity in Response in REST Java WS?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I try to send in Response some object, but i wasn't successful. I am using Glassfish Jersey libraries.

There is snippet code from server side Service:

```
@Override
@PUT
@Path("/employees")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response addEmployee(@FormParam("firstName") String fname, @FormParam("lastName") String lname,
                              @FormParam("salary") BigDecimal salary,
                              @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    init();
    Integer id = manageEmployee.addEmployee(fname, lname, salary);
    GenericEntity<Integer> genericid = new GenericEntity<Integer>(id) {};
    return Response.ok(genericid).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
}
```

And there is attempt to get Integer again on client:

```
@Override
public Integer addEmployee(String fname, String lname, BigDecimal salary) {
Form form = new Form();
form.param("firstName", fname);
form.param("lastName", lname);
form.param("salary", salary.toString());
Response response = client.target(REST_SERVICE_URL).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .put(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));
Integer  genericid = response.readEntity(new GenericType<Integer>() {});

System.out.println("Test case name: test addEmployee, Result: " + genericid);
return genericid;
}
```

Issue from Console:

```
test add employee Web Service Method
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html;charset=utf-8, type=class java.lang.Integer, genericType=class java.lang.Integer.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:834)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:368)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$2.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:419)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.runInScopeIfPossible(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:123)
    at com.deepam.ExampleHibernateEmployeeRESTfulTester.addEmployee(ExampleHibernateEmployeeRESTfulTester.java:83)
    at com.deepam.ExampleHibernateEmployeeRESTfulTester.main(ExampleHibernateEmployeeRESTfulTester.java:154)
```

I am wonder, that response is formatted as text/html (first line - media type=text/html).
Can anybody explain me, what is wrong?

Comment: how is `Integer` generic?

Comment: try GenericEntity<T> genericid = new GenericEntity<T>(id) {};

Answer (score 0):

This question is my misunderstanding. Parameters in `Form` class are natively `String`. Than native manner is to receive on the server side again `String` to avoid the problems with `null`, bad format etc. Conversion to proper object can be done after reguest is done. This is the first thing. So I decided to supply `BigDecimal` to `String` in `@FormParam("salary") BigDecimal salary`, clause. Second thing is the `Integer` as `GenericType/GenericEntity` in response. Again. The simplest way is to send `String` and wrap it in into 'Integer' back on the client side to avoid the types of error as `500 - server internal error`, `class Integer has no its Default constructor` etc.